# Easy way to donate a few dollars to charity, manually, every day?

Tags: charity, charitable-contributions

(I hope this is not off-topic, and apologies if it is)

---

I'm looking for an easy way to donate a few dollars to charity every day (possibly different amounts, depending on the day).

Requirements:

- I want to choose the amount, daily
- I prefer not to re-login or re-enter my credit card every time
- I'd like to have some choice in what cause my money goes to

Is there a web site that does this?

I spent a lot of time googling, but as you might expect, the search results for something like this are garbage.

Comment: So what you are imagining is some kind of website where you get a list of charities and then you just click on one and enter how much you want to donate and the website does the rest?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service recommendations or other off-site resources are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: @Philipp Precisely. The site would need to be reputable though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of web sites that review charities.  One that I have used is call CharityNavigator.  It provides a lot of specific information for 1000's of charities, ranks them, and permits you to compare them side by side.

It does not meet all of your requirements.  The minimum donation is $10 per charity.  You can select multiple charities and donate to all of them at once with one payment (credit card or Paypal) but I don't know if they store your method of payment so that you do not have to reenter the information each time.